# Conversion of strings containing non printable characters

Tags: c#, encoding, non-printable

I would like to convert a byte array containing non printable characters to string for my application. When I convert back to byte array, the contents of the array should remain the same as I found that ASCII/Unicode/UTF8 doesnt always give me the right solution?

E.g

```
 byte[] bytearray ={ 147, 35, 44, 18, 255, 104, 206, 72 ,69};

 string str = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytearray);

 bytearray = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
```

In the above example, I find that the byte array contains

```
{ 63, 35, 44, 18, 63, 104, 63, 72 ,69}.
```

Kindly help me.

Comment: See also: http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2010/03/binary-data-and-strings.html

Comment: @DavidNeale it sounds like it is just a hunk of bytes - nothing to do with encoding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [Convert.ToBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx) method. It will convert a byte array into string. Have in mind that encoded into string that data will take up more space than your original byte array would.

```
public static string ToBase64String(
    byte[] inArray
)
```

You can then decode string back to byte array using `FromBase64String`

```
public static byte[] FromBase64String(
    string s
)
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>I think that your problem is that you are using the wrong encoding. ASCII defines 128 characters (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) and so will never give you bytes above 128.</s>

You need to find your correct encoding and use that if you expect a return trip to be successful.

I misread the question it seems. My answer was only relevant if the byte array was an encoded string - I hadn't read the bit that said that it was unprintable characters, etc. Nikola's answer is the one to go for. :)

Comment: no; this is not a job for Encoding; Encoding is string => byte[] => string; this question is byte[] => string => byte[] - base-64 or hex-encoding is correct; Encoding is wrong.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Yeah, my bad. I didn't read the question. I thought he had a text string as bytes since he was using encoding. It was only afterwards I realised that some of the characters would be non-printing and then saw your comment and read the question properly. That -1 will make me remember to read the question properly in future. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

### Use a different Encoding base as ASCII will change all non-printable chars to ? being 63.

When the string doesn't have to be a human readable version of the non-prontable chars indeed converting it to base64 (UUEncode/XXEncode) would indeed do the trick.

Comment: no; this is not a job for Encoding; Encoding is string => byte[] => string; this question is byte[] => string => byte[] - base-64 or hex-encoding is correct; Encoding is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your using the ASCI encoding to convery your byte array to string, remember that ASCI is a 7 bit protocol, the encoding will either strip the eigth bit or fall back to a specific value (the documentation seems unclear which it does!)

To quote MSDN;

> Prior to the .NET Framework version 2.0, the .NET Framework allowed
>   spoofing by ignoring the 8th bit. Beginning with the .NET Framework
>   2.0, non-ASCII code points fall back during decoding.